# why is vim's delete command so slow

Tags: vim

I have a file that contains about 5000 lines and I want to delete all lines that have 'some_string' so I first search for `/some_string` then I execute `:g//d`. This takes over 5 minutes to delete ~90% of the lines. What gives?

In comparison, if I run `sed -i '/some_string/d' some_file` it takes 46ms.

Comment: I just took a file with 180000 lines and ran a similar command. 3170 lines were removed in a blink of time, less than 0.1 sec. I believe your problem is not with vim.

Comment: Does the same issue happen when you run vim without a `.vimrc` file?

Comment: Does your `some_string` contain any special characters? Maybe this isn't a simple pattern. See `:help magic` for how vim's regex language differs from others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an underscore to your command.

I experienced a similar problem and it turned out to be each line being copied to my system clipboard. By adding a `_`, you tell vim to use the blackhole register.

```
:g//d_
```

The help gives the following syntax for `:d`

```
:[range]d[elete] [x]   Delete [range] lines (default: current line) [into register x].
```